# Function not been detected on unchecking of checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox that, if I check it, redirects to another function as shown in the following code:

```
function Allchecks1(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            var market = $(event.target).closest('a');
            var destination = market.attr('data-destination');
            if ((destination == 'null' || destination == 'local') && market.attr('dataid')) {
                var id = market.attr('dataid');
                navigateToEvent(id); // Passes the ID to this function
                return true;   
            }
            else if (!$('#cb').is(':checked')) {
                alert("owiedjiej");     // Did a test when I uncheck the textbox; nothing happened
            }  
        }

function navigateToEvent(id) {
            var url = '/' + 'List/events/';
            if (id)
                url += id;
        }
```

The code above passes the ID to the function `navigateToEvent()` so the output for example is as follows:

```
/List/events/1111
```

What I am trying to achieve is, that when I untick the checkbox, the ID should be removed and my expected output should be:

```
/List/events/
```

How do I achieve this? I added an alert just for testing purposes on the unticking of the checkbox and it doesnt fire any alerts.

HTML:

```
<li "><a  data-destination="local" dataid="' + this.MarketID + '" data-nodeid = "' + this.NodeId + '" ><span><input type="checkbox" id="cb" onclick=Allchecks1(event);></span></a></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach so that you can easily track click of checkbox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cb").click(function(){
if($('#cb').is(':checked')){
 alert("The paragraph was checked.");
} else {
 alert("The paragraph was unchecked.");
}
});
});
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo here,i have it as #cb in my code,it still doesnt work

Comment: Then instead of calling like this.Why don't u use jQuery click function to checkbox??

Answer (score 0):

At the most moment of firing the code it is checked after firing it then  it will be unchecked so change your code as this

```
else if ($('#cb').is(':checked')) {
```